# MUI x-data-grid | Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I have recently implemented MUI x-data-grid into my app, initially it was working fine but my app later started getting crashed giving me this error:

[image]

Now, I am not using `apiRef` or object or anything so I have no clue how to fix it,
Here is my code:

```
const DataTable: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { rows, columns, showPagination, onPageChange, onRowChange, paginationValues } =
    props;
  const [rowSelectionModel, setRowSelectionModel] = React.useState<GridRowSelectionModel>(
    []
  );

  return (
    <>
      {rows?.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            getRowId={(row) => row.id}
            autoHeight
            autoPageSize
            checkboxSelection
            hideFooter
            hideFooterPagination
            disableColumnFilter
            disableColumnMenu
            disableRowSelectionOnClick
            rowCount={parseInt(paginationValues?.count || "0")}
            paginationMode="server"
            onRowSelectionModelChange={(newRowSelectionModel, details) => {
              setRowSelectionModel(newRowSelectionModel);
              props.onRowSelectionModelChange?.(newRowSelectionModel, details);
            }}
            rowSelectionModel={rowSelectionModel}
            loading={props.loading}
            keepNonExistentRowsSelected={true}
            className={classes.dataTable}
            onRowClick={props.onRowClick}
            slots={{
              columnSortedAscendingIcon: ArrowDropUpIcon,
              columnSortedDescendingIcon: ArrowDropDownIcon
            }}
          />
          {showPagination && rows && rows?.length > 0 && (
            <DataTablePagination
              rowsPerPage={Number.parseInt(paginationValues?.rowsPerPage || "10")}
              currentPage={Number.parseInt(paginationValues?.page || "1")}
              count={Number.parseInt(paginationValues?.pages || "0")}
              onPageChange={onPageChange}
              paginationValues={paginationValues}
              setRowsPerPage={onRowChange}
            />
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <EmptyData />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default DataTable;
```

and here is how I am using this component:

```
<DataTable
            rows={productsToShow}
            columns={columns}
            paginationValues={pagination}
            onPageChange={handlePageChange}
            onRowChange={handleRowChange}
            showPagination
            loading={isLoading}
            onRowSelectionModelChange={(newRowSelectionModel) => {
              const newSelectedProducts: ProductData[] = [];
              newRowSelectionModel.forEach((id) => {
                const oldProducts = selectedProducts.find((product) => id === product.id);
                if (!oldProducts) {
                  const foundProduct = products?.results.find(
                    (product) => id === product.id
                  );
                  if (foundProduct) {
                    newSelectedProducts.push(foundProduct);
                  }
                } else {
                  newSelectedProducts.push(oldProducts);
                }
              });
              setSelectedProducts(newSelectedProducts);
            }}
          />
```

I have tried deleting node_modules and yarn lock file and reinstalling dependencies but it did not work and I could not find any relevant  issue on the Github repo, all of the issues in which current problem is happening are using `apiRef` and I am not. I tried setting timeout too. HELP!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was trying to use DataGrid inside a modal popup and I was using `autoWidth` and `autoHeight` attributes. Removing those fixed the issue for me.

**Explanation**
So these attributes use ref which typically works for the elements present on the DOM but since the table was in the popup the elements were not on DOM causing ref to be null.